# React Native, passing authentication token to index

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm creating an app where navigational components are held in the index. On startup, you are automatically taken to the login page. At this log in page, the user will be given an authentication token. How can I get this token back to the index so that it can be used throughout the rest of the app? Thanks!

index.android.js

```
//lots of imports
export default class CBURecCenterApp extends Component {

constructor(){
    super()
    this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this)
}

renderScene(route, navigator){
    switch(route.name){
        case 'Home':
            return <HomePage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Calendar':
            return <CalendarPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Events':
            return <EventsPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Discover':
            return <DiscoverPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Profile':
            return <ProfilePage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Settings':
            return <SettingsPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Info':
            return <InfoPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Login':
            return <LoginPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        case 'Register':
            return <RegisterPage navigator={navigator} />
            break;
        default:
            return <ErrorPage navigator={navigator} />
    }
}
render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{name: 'Login'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}

 AppRegistry.registerComponent('CBURecCenterApp', () => CBURecCenterApp);
```

LoginPage.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-    native';
import Api from '../Utility/Api';


export default class LoginPage extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        userName: null,
        password: null
      };
  }

  navigate(name){
      this.props.navigator.push({
          name
      })
  }

  submitLogin(){
    response: Api.login(
        this.state.userName,
        this.state.password
    );
    if(response.status === 200){
        //pass authentication token to index.android.js
        //navigate to home page
    }
    else{
        //invalid username/password handling code
    }
  }

render(){
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                onChangeText={(userName) => this.setState({userName})}
                value={this.state.userName}
                keyboardType = {'email-address'}
                autoCorrect = {false}
                placeholder = {'CBU Email'}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                value={this.state.password}
                keyboardType = {'email-address'}
                autoCorrect = {false}
                placeholder = {'password'}
                secureTextEntry={ true }
            />
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
textField: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use local storage to check authentication

```
this.props.login({
    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password
}, function(err, token) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if(token) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem("jwt", token, this._navToOffers);

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to simply pass a prop into the navigator, I learned that this could be achieved by simply passing the prop when i push to the navigation stack.

```
      navigate(name){
      this.props.navigator.push({
          name: name,
          token: this.state.response
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you need to pass the token access through multiple components in your app, obviously to access the server from multiple places. The typical solution here to do and most users use is to implement Redux, another framwork of JavaScript just as React Native that allows you to pass data and a Global State of your app through the props of a Component.

This way, your token would be stored to the "Store" of Redux, and yout Components could access to it.

At first Redux  seems to be difficult to use but once you understand the basics and the complex terminology you'll be fine.

Here's the docs of Redux: https://es.redux.js.org/

And an Udemy course I think it could help: https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/